# How to add 2 different onclick methods in HTML link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I don't know how to add this 2 action for onclick html link, someone can help me?

the first:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

the second:

```
onclick='document.cookie="firstname=John;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT"'
```

I want someting like this:

```
<a href="Tabs.html" onclick=" 'myFunction();' 'document.cookie="firstname=John;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT";' ">
    Start <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: You should use js/jQuery to bind event.

Comment: When I look at inline event handlers, my heart bleeds blood! pls don't kill me!

Comment: To point out the fundamental errors: You don't need to wrap your statements in single quotes in `onclick` and mixing double quotes within double quotes without escaping will confuse the HTML parser. Just treat `onclick` as a single line of JavaScript that gets executed. Multiple statements possible if divided by semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pretend that inside the `onclick` there's a body function, so for example:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="alert('a');alert('e');">Start <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-lg"></i> </a>
```

In your case, you can write:

```
<a href="Tabs.html" onclick="myFunction(); document.cookie='firstname=John;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT'">Start <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-lg"></i> </a>
```

However, it's bad habit to write js directly inside the html tag... you should consider to add the event listener from a script

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way, wrapping in a function the two operations you need to do:

```
onclick="clickFunction();"
```

clickFunction():

```
function clickFunction() {
     myFunction();
     document.cookie="firstname=John;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="Tabs.html" onclick="myFunction(); document.cookie='firstname=John;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT';">
Start <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It might not be pretty but it's correct.